# .NET HTTP Request Timeout not "Aborting" on continuous streaming site

Tags: c#, httprequest

**Scope**

I have developed a Wrapper for the [Http Web Request](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.net.httpwebrequest%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class to execute Gets and Posts in an easier way. This library is being used without any problem for over two years already, but today, we faced a weird problem.

There's [one website](http://anus.io/) (it will take a while to load), that apparently, keeps streaming characters to the HTML frontend, so our library "Get" request gets stuck into a loop.

**Different Timeout Properties**

Looking at the Http Web Request reference we find that there are two different `timeout` properties. We are using both of them, but none of them seem to abort properly.

- [Read Write Timeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.readwritetimeout(v=vs.110).aspx) - Gets or sets a time-out in milliseconds when writing to or reading from a stream.
- [Timeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.timeout(v=vs.110).aspx) - Gets or sets the time-out value in milliseconds for the GetResponse and GetRequestStream methods.

**One Timeout to Rule them all**

Is there any way to set an "Operation Timeout" that will force the stream/connection disposing after some pre-configured time?

**Some Code Sample**

```
public class Program
{
public static void Main()
{
    string url = "http://anus.io";

    Console.WriteLine("Initializing Request State Object");

    RequestState myRequestState = new RequestState();

    // Creating Http Request
    myRequestState.request  =  (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    myRequestState.request.Method           = "GET";
    myRequestState.request.ReadWriteTimeout = 4000;
    myRequestState.request.Timeout          = 4000;

    Console.WriteLine("Begining Async Request");


    IAsyncResult ar = myRequestState.request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(ResponseCallback), myRequestState);

    Console.WriteLine("Waiting for Results");
    ar.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();

    myRequestState.response = (HttpWebResponse)myRequestState.request.EndGetResponse(ar);
    Console.WriteLine("Response status code = {0}", myRequestState.response.StatusCode);

}

public static void ResponseCallback (IAsyncResult asyncResult)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Completed");
}
}
```

[This Code seem to work fine](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Ku6gU5), but how do i read the response as string, since it is being constantly transmited (as the browser shows)?

**Question**

What's the proper way to handle websites like this ? (By handle I mean to be able to identify and skip situations where the server simply won't stop transmitting?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
public static void Main()
{

    string url = "http://anus.io";

    ***int DefaultTimeOut = 15000;*** //timeout after 15 sec

    Console.WriteLine("Initializing Request State Object");

    RequestState myRequestState = new RequestState();

    // Creating Http Request
    myRequestState.request  =  (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    myRequestState.request.Method           = "GET";
    myRequestState.request.ReadWriteTimeout = 4000;
    myRequestState.request.Timeout          = 4000;

    Console.WriteLine("Begining Async Request");


    IAsyncResult ar = myRequestState.request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(ResponseCallback), myRequestState);

    ***ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject(ar.AsyncWaitHandle, new WaitOrTimerCallback(TimeoutCallback), myRequestState.request, DefaultTimeOut, true);***

    Console.WriteLine("Waiting for Results");
    ar.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();

    try{

    myRequestState.response = (HttpWebResponse)myRequestState.request.EndGetResponse(ar);
    Console.WriteLine("Response status code = {0}", myRequestState.response.StatusCode);
    }catch(Exception){
       Console.WriteLine("Request Aborted");
    }
}

public static void ResponseCallback (IAsyncResult asyncResult)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Completed");
}

//call the timeout if more than 15 seconds

**public static void TimeoutCallback(object state, bool timedOut)
{
            if (timedOut)
            {
                HttpWebRequest request = state as HttpWebRequest;
                if (request != null)
                {
                    request.Abort();
                }
            }
}**
```

Answer (score 0):

I would move the entire HTTP processing into a `Task` and use a generic technique to put a timeout on that task. Many such techniques are available.

I don't see why you need so many individual timeouts. Can't you just say: If this requests takes longer than 4 seconds, no matter the reason, kill it.

The APM pattern and waiting for events are red flags in the age of .NET 4.5 and C# 5. All of that junk obscures the intention of your code. The junk goes away if you use `await` to use async IO provided by the `WebRequest` class and use a generic timeout technique wrapped around it.